# Gunicorn fails when using WSGI

Tags: python, python-2.7, wsgi, gunicorn, tilestache

I want Gunicorn to talk with TileStache via WSGI. But when I run this command...

```
gunicorn "TileStache:WSGITileServer('/var/osm/bright/project/OSMBright4/tilestache.cfg')"
```

...I get these errors:

```
2013-03-30 23:02:41 [14300] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.2
2013-03-30 23:02:41 [14300] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (14300)
2013-03-30 23:02:41 [14300] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-03-30 23:02:41 [14305] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14305
Error loading Tilestache config:
2013-03-30 23:02:41 [14305] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 485, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 103, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 25, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 381, in import_app
    app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self.config = parseConfigfile(config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/__init__.py", line 166, in parseConfigfile
    return Config.buildConfiguration(config_dict, dirpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/Config.py", line 217, in buildConfiguration
    config.layers[name] = _parseConfigfileLayer(layer_dict, config, dirpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/Config.py", line 441, in _parseConfigfileLayer
    layer.provider = _class(layer, **provider_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/Mapnik.py", line 81, in __init__
    engine = mapnik.FontEngine.instance()
NameError: global name 'mapnik' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 485, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 103, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 25, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 381, in import_app
    app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self.config = parseConfigfile(config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/__init__.py", line 166, in parseConfigfile
    return Config.buildConfiguration(config_dict, dirpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/Config.py", line 217, in buildConfiguration
    config.layers[name] = _parseConfigfileLayer(layer_dict, config, dirpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/Config.py", line 441, in _parseConfigfileLayer
    layer.provider = _class(layer, **provider_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/Mapnik.py", line 81, in __init__
    engine = mapnik.FontEngine.instance()
NameError: global name 'mapnik' is not defined
2013-03-30 23:02:41 [14305] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14305)
2013-03-30 23:02:41 [14300] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2013-03-30 23:02:41 [14300] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Does anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

It came up, as Karmel mentioned, that the problem lay in Mapnik and TileStache, and not Gunicorn.

After some research I found out that there has been [changes of the python module name](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/Mapnik2) through the different versions; it was `mapnik` until version 2.0 when it changed to `mapnik2`, and then back to `mapnik` again at version 2.1. And obviously it appeared that I had installed version 2.0.

I suppose I just could have changed to `import mapnik2` in `TileStache/mapnik.py`, but I thought it would be more future friendly to uninstall Mapnik and then [build it from source](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/master/INSTALL.md#building) instead. It took a while, but definitely worth it.

A big thanks to [Karmel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284636) for putting me at the right track!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have python-mapnik installed? The error appears to be in the configuration of TileStache and mapnik rather than gunicorn or WSGI. If you look at TileStache/Mapknik.py (I am looking here: https://github.com/migurski/TileStache/blob/master/TileStache/Mapnik.py), you see that the initial import of mapnik passes on the error:

```
try:
    import mapnik
except ImportError:
    # can still build documentation
    pass
```

but that will cause problems in line 81 when mapnik is expected to be there. So, make sure you apt-get install python-mapnik or otherwise ensure mapnik is in your Python path.

Comment: I have `python-mapnik2` installed, I guess that's the same. But Mapnik isn't in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`. Although, a search among my installed packages gives me `libmapnik2-2.2`, `mapnik-utils` and `python-mapnik2`.

Comment: If you go to the python command line and try to `import mapnik`, does it work?

Comment: I found it out, see my answer. :-)